# Netbeans isn't show my gui project with java

Tags: java, swing

I want to simple project with java GUI in Netbeans , I have two class and I want to when i click button in NewJInternalFrame class , it will show me CustomerChoose class but when I click it doesn't show anything,

```
package javaapplication1;



/**
 *
 * @author lll
 */
public final class NewJInternalFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

 
    /**
     * Creates new form NewJInternalFrame
     */
    public NewJInternalFrame() {
      
        initComponents();
    }
    
   
  
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        panel1 = new java.awt.Panel();
        jToggleButton3 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));

        panel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));

        jToggleButton1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/javaapplication1/images/icons8-customer-32.png"))); // NOI18N
        jToggleButton1.setText("customer");
        jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

      

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 153));

        jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/javaapplication1/images/bank (1).png"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("bank system");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 195, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel1);
        panel1.setLayout(panel1Layout);
        panel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(235, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(panel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(panel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(panel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 555, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        //setVisible(false);
        new CustomerChoose().setVisible(true);     
    }                                              
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
             new NewJInternalFrame().setVisible(true);
         });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private java.awt.Panel panel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

when i click jToggleButton1 i want to see new window like this:

```
public class CustomerChoose extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

 
    public CustomerChoose() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

       
        panel8 = new java.awt.Panel();
        

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Narrow", 0, 16)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("xxx");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panel8Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel8);
        panel8.setLayout(panel8Layout);
 

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void panel8MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                   
    
    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
             new CustomerChoose().setVisible(true);
         });
    }


 
    private java.awt.Panel panel8;
 
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

But when i click it doesn't show anything. What is the wrong?

Comment: JInternalFrame doesn't display on its own but rather displays within a JDesktopPane as per [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html). You probably don't want to create a JInternalFrame but rather will want to create and display a JDIalog. .

Comment: Note that the question has nothing to do with NetBeans and all to do with understanding the basics of the Swing GUI library. I urge you to go to the [Swing Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) to learn more.